# Building CPLEX fails in Julia

Tags: julia, cplex

I am trying to install CPLEX in Julia on a computer cluster. I got the following error when I did Pkg.build("CPLEX"). It seems that I didn't pass the right path. I know how to correct it on my local computer but could anyone tell me how to fix it on a computer cluster? Or is it because of some other problems?

For your information,

CPLEX version: 12.10-GCCcore-8.3.0,
Julia version: 1.7.1.

Thanks very much in advance.

Hongyu.

```
The versions of CPLEX supported by CPLEX.jl are:

* 12.10
* 20.1

You must download and install one of these versions separately.

You should set the `CPLEX_STUDIO_BINARIES` environment variable to point to
the install location then try again. For example (updating the path to the
correct location):


ENV["CPLEX_STUDIO_BINARIES"] = "/opt/CPLEX_Studio201/cplex/bin/x86-64_linux/"
import Pkg
Pkg.add("CPLEX")
Pkg.build("CPLEX")


See the CPLEX.jl README at https://github.com/jump-dev/CPLEX.jl for further
instructions.

Stacktrace:
 [1] error(s::String)
   @ Base ./error.jl:33
 [2] try_local_installation()
   @ Main ~/.julia/packages/CPLEX/88lum/deps/build.jl:132
 [3] top-level scope
   @ ~/.julia/packages/CPLEX/88lum/deps/build.jl:150
 [4] include(fname::String)
   @ Base.MainInclude ./client.jl:451
 [5] top-level scope
   @ none:5
in expression starting at /home/hongyuzh/.julia/packages/CPLEX/88lum/deps/build.jl:143
Stacktrace:
  [1] pkgerror(msg::String)
    @ Pkg.Types /share/apps/Julia/1.7.1-linux-x86_64/share/julia/stdlib/v1.7/Pkg/src/Types.jl:68
  [2] (::Pkg.Operations.var"#62#67"{Bool, Pkg.Types.Context, String, Pkg.Types.PackageSpec})()
    @ Pkg.Operations /share/apps/Julia/1.7.1-linux-x86_64/share/julia/stdlib/v1.7/Pkg/src/Operations.jl:962
  [3] withenv(::Pkg.Operations.var"#62#67"{Bool, Pkg.Types.Context, String, Pkg.Types.PackageSpec}, ::Pair{String, String}, ::Vararg{Pair{String}})
    @ Base ./env.jl:172
  [4] (::Pkg.Operations.var"#99#103"{String, Bool, Bool, Bool, Pkg.Operations.var"#62#67"{Bool, Pkg.Types.Context, String, Pkg.Types.PackageSpec}, Pkg.Types.PackageSpec})()
    @ Pkg.Operations /share/apps/Julia/1.7.1-linux-x86_64/share/julia/stdlib/v1.7/Pkg/src/Operations.jl:1506
  [5] with_temp_env(fn::Pkg.Operations.var"#99#103"{String, Bool, Bool, Bool, Pkg.Operations.var"#62#67"{Bool, Pkg.Types.Context, String, Pkg.Types.PackageSpec}, Pkg.Types.PackageSpec}, temp_env::String)
    @ Pkg.Operations /share/apps/Julia/1.7.1-linux-x86_64/share/julia/stdlib/v1.7/Pkg/src/Operations.jl:1390
  [6] (::Pkg.Operations.var"#98#102"{Bool, Bool, Bool, Pkg.Operations.var"#62#67"{Bool, Pkg.Types.Context, String, Pkg.Types.PackageSpec}, Pkg.Types.Context, Pkg.Types.PackageSpec, String, Pkg.Types.Project, String})(tmp::String)
    @ Pkg.Operations /share/apps/Julia/1.7.1-linux-x86_64/share/julia/stdlib/v1.7/Pkg/src/Operations.jl:1469
  [7] mktempdir(fn::Pkg.Operations.var"#98#102"{Bool, Bool, Bool, Pkg.Operations.var"#62#67"{Bool, Pkg.Types.Context, String, Pkg.Types.PackageSpec}, Pkg.Types.Context, Pkg.Types.PackageSpec, String, Pkg.Types.Project, String}, parent::String; prefix::String)
    @ Base.Filesystem ./file.jl:750
  [8] mktempdir(fn::Function, parent::String) (repeats 2 times)
    @ Base.Filesystem ./file.jl:748
  [9] sandbox(fn::Function, ctx::Pkg.Types.Context, target::Pkg.Types.PackageSpec, target_path::String, sandbox_path::String, sandbox_project_override::Pkg.Types.Project; force_latest_compatible_version::Bool, allow_earlier_backwards_compatible_versions::Bool, allow_reresolve::Bool)
    @ Pkg.Operations /share/apps/Julia/1.7.1-linux-x86_64/share/julia/stdlib/v1.7/Pkg/src/Operations.jl:1435
 [10] sandbox(fn::Function, ctx::Pkg.Types.Context, target::Pkg.Types.PackageSpec, target_path::String, sandbox_path::String, sandbox_project_override::Pkg.Types.Project)
    @ Pkg.Operations /share/apps/Julia/1.7.1-linux-x86_64/share/julia/stdlib/v1.7/Pkg/src/Operations.jl:1432
 [11] build_versions(ctx::Pkg.Types.Context, uuids::Set{Base.UUID}; verbose::Bool)
    @ Pkg.Operations /share/apps/Julia/1.7.1-linux-x86_64/share/julia/stdlib/v1.7/Pkg/src/Operations.jl:943
 [12] build(ctx::Pkg.Types.Context, uuids::Set{Base.UUID}, verbose::Bool)
    @ Pkg.Operations /share/apps/Julia/1.7.1-linux-x86_64/share/julia/stdlib/v1.7/Pkg/src/Operations.jl:822
 [13] build(ctx::Pkg.Types.Context, pkgs::Vector{Pkg.Types.PackageSpec}; verbose::Bool, kwargs::Base.Pairs{Symbol, Base.TTY, Tuple{Symbol}, NamedTuple{(:io,), Tuple{Base.TTY}}})
    @ Pkg.API /share/apps/Julia/1.7.1-linux-x86_64/share/julia/stdlib/v1.7/Pkg/src/API.jl:992
 [14] build(pkgs::Vector{Pkg.Types.PackageSpec}; io::Base.TTY, kwargs::Base.Pairs{Symbol, Union{}, Tuple{}, NamedTuple{(), Tuple{}}})
    @ Pkg.API /share/apps/Julia/1.7.1-linux-x86_64/share/julia/stdlib/v1.7/Pkg/src/API.jl:149
 [15] build(pkgs::Vector{Pkg.Types.PackageSpec})
    @ Pkg.API /share/apps/Julia/1.7.1-linux-x86_64/share/julia/stdlib/v1.7/Pkg/src/API.jl:144
 [16] #build#99
    @ /share/apps/Julia/1.7.1-linux-x86_64/share/julia/stdlib/v1.7/Pkg/src/API.jl:142 [inlined]
 [17] build
    @ /share/apps/Julia/1.7.1-linux-x86_64/share/julia/stdlib/v1.7/Pkg/src/API.jl:142 [inlined]
 [18] #build#98
    @ /share/apps/Julia/1.7.1-linux-x86_64/share/julia/stdlib/v1.7/Pkg/src/API.jl:141 [inlined]
 [19] build(pkg::String)
    @ Pkg.API /share/apps/Julia/1.7.1-linux-x86_64/share/julia/stdlib/v1.7/Pkg/src/API.jl:141
 [20] top-level scope
    @ REPL[138]:1
```

Comment: Did you try setting `ENV["CPLEX_STUDIO_BINARIES"]` as the message mentions? Is the problem that you don't know what the path is in these machines, or something else?

Comment: @SundarR Thanks for your answer. I tried to set the environment but I still got the same error. I am not sure if it is because I provide the wrong path or the version of CPLEX is not right. So now there are two questions, 1. how can we find path of CPLEX on Linux and 2. What is the difference between 12.10-GCCcore-8.3.0 and 12.10 of CPLEX? Sorry, I am not very familiar with the Linux command line. They may be very simple to Linux users.

Comment: (1) Try `which cplex` on the Linux console and see if that returns a path. (2) If not, try these paths for the `CPLEX_STUDIO_BINARIES` one by one, `build` after each one and see if that's the correct one: (i) `"/opt/CPLEX_Studio1210/cplex/bin/x86-64_linux/"` (ii) `"/opt/CPLEX_Studio12100/cplex/bin/x86-64_linux/"` (iii) `"/opt/ibm/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio1210/cplex/bin/x86-64_linux/"` (iv) `"/opt/ibm/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio12100/cplex/bin/x86-64_linux/"`

Comment: Thanks! I got a path after `which cplex`, /share/apps/CPLEX/12.10-GCCcore-8.3.0/cplex/bin/x86-64_linux/cplex. I tried this path but didn't work. Then I tried the other four options also didn't work.

Comment: That's progress! Are you sure the path starts with `/share` and not `/usr/share`? In either case, you have to remove the final `cplex` from the path before saving it into `ENV`.

Comment: and once you get the correct ENV remember to `Pkg.build("CPLEX")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(Solution found in comment discussion, adding as answer for better visibility.)*

As the error message indicates, you have to set the `ENV["CPLEX_STUDIO_BINARIES"]` value to the directory that contains `cplex`. You can find that by running `which cplex | xargs dirname` (or simply `which cplex` and removing the final `cplex` from the result yourself).

One you set `CPLEX_STUDIO_BINARIES` to that path, you can run `Pkg.build("CPLEX")` again to let CPLEX.jl pick up the binaries from the path.